# How to use VSCode with the existing docker container

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

I've made an Python+Django+git docker container.
Now, I would like to 'Attach to a running container..' with VSCode to develop, i.e. run and debug, a Python app inside.
Is it good idea? Or it is better only setting up VSCode to run app inside the container?
I don't want VSCode make a docker container by itself.
Thanks.

I tried to 'Attach to a running container..' but have got 'error xhr failed...' etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got good results with VSCode using **docker compose** with **compose.yml**. But in this case, **docker compose** will create a new container from image every time.

**compose.yml example:**

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  my_container:
    image: python_find_a_job:lts
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true        # docker run -t
    container_name: find_a_job
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - ~/.PYTHON/find_a_job:/opt/find_a_job
  mongodb_container:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db
volumes:
  mongodb_data_container:
```

**Before work:**

```
docker compose up
```

VSCode / Attach to Running Container ...

File / Open Folder (/opt/find_a_job from above example of compose.yml).

**After work:**

```
docker compose down
```

P.S. I have tried *PyCharm community ed*. But it can't add Docker interpreter. Only *PyCharm Professional ed.* can do it.

So I use VSCode to run & debug (F5) inside a docker container. There was some minor problems with setting VSCode tasks, extensions etc. But main part about run & debug inside a container works perfect. Changes in a project can be saved locally or pushed to git by VSCode or manually.

Comment: If you add a "build: <subdir of Dockerfile>" node to the compose, then `docker compose build` can be used to rebuilt the image when needed.

Answer (score 1):

**I use such an environment to develop python app inside a container.**

```
image_create.sh # script to create image to use it local and on the server

image_dockerfile # dockerfile with script how to create an image

container_create.sh  # create named container from image

container_restart.sh # restart existing container

container_stop.sh  # stop existing container
```

Examples:

image_dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.9.15-slim-bullseye
USER root
RUN pip3 install requests telethon
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get --assume-yes install git
```

image_create.sh :

```
docker rmi python_find_a_job:lts
docker build . -f python_find_a_job -t python_find_a_job:lts
```

container_create.sh :

```
docker rm -f python_find_a_job
docker run -t -d --name python_find_a_job -i python_find_a_job:lts
docker ps -aq
```

container_restart.sh :

```
docker container restart python_find_a_job
docker ps -aq
```

container_stop.sh :

```
docker stop python_find_a_job
docker ps -aq
```

**For VSCcode:**

a) Prepare files (see above).

b) Run:

image_create.sh

container_create.sh

c) Open project folder in VSCode

d) Click on left bottom green / Attach to running container / select container name (python_find_a_job).

e) Clone repository.

f) Install extension 'Python'.

Now you can run and debug inside the container.

**After work:**

git push

container_stop.sh

**Before work:**

container_restart.sh

git pull

Comment: Something to try is switching to a `Makefile`. I find a `Makefile` easier to maintain than a collection of shell scripts. Also, rather than starting and stopping containers directly, create a `compose.yml`, as when the project grows to include other containers this makes the dependencies easy to manage.

Comment: @JialeDu, thank you for the remainder. I would like to collect here all that I have got about this situation before to close the question.

Comment: @Chris Becke, thanks. I have tried **compose.yml** and it works better. I will put here all I know about using **compose.yml**. Thank you for info about using a **Makefile**!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code, and Docker Desktop each offer a feature called "Dev Containers" (VSCode) or "Dev Environments" (DD), or CodeSpaces (GitHub)

In this approach, a Docker container is created by scanning the source, and generating a container that contains the development toolchain. Visual Studio then attaches to the container, and allows you to develop even though you do not have node/python3/dotnet/etc. installed on your development PC.

The xhr error indicates something went wrong downloading a scanning image or something else is strange about your project.
There is an optional Dockerfile that can be created if scanning fails to find an image, that is normally kept in a `.devcontainers` / `.devenvironments` folder depending on which of Docker / VSCode / GitHub / other you are using.

Your project might also have one (or more) Dockerfile's that are used to package the running app up as a docker image, so don't be confused if you end up with 2. Thats not a problem and is expected really.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to use my own docker container. To have a possibility, for example, to use PyCharm Community. To be independent from VSCode and its plugins. Maybe is there an example how to use such self-made container to run & debug app inside?